# Find the last 3 digits of ${341}^{101}+ {309}^{201}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion

I was trying to solve it with  Fermat–Euler theorem, but this didn't help me with anything. Please give a hint. Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion this is a duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619) "mother" thread, See for example [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1499273/11619) for adaptations when looking for a few of the last digits in particular.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$341^{101}=(1+340)^{101}\equiv1+\binom{101}1340+\binom{101}2340^2\pmod{1000}$$

$$309^{201}=(310-1)^{201}=-(1-310)^{201}$$

$$(1-310)^{201}\equiv1-\binom{201}1310+\binom{201}2310^2\pmod{1000}$$

Now $\displaystyle\binom{101}134=(100+1)34\equiv34\pmod{100}\implies\binom{101}1340\equiv340\pmod{1000}$

and  $\displaystyle\binom{101}234^2=101\cdot34^2\equiv6\pmod{10}\implies\binom{101}2340^2\equiv600\pmod{1000}$

Comment: Just change the signal on second line. (+1) anyway.

Comment: @Arnaldo, Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce modulo $1000 = 125\cdot 8$; the Chinese Remainder Theorem can help.  First note that $\phi(125) = 100$, so you have

$$x=341^{101}+309^{201} \equiv 341 +309 \equiv 650  \pmod{125}.$$

Second, note that every odd number to an even power is congruent to $1$ modulo $8$, so you have

$$x=341^{101}+309^{201} \equiv 341+309 \equiv 650  \pmod{8}.$$

Finally, by CRT, $x\equiv 650 \pmod{125\cdot 8}.$

Answer (score 1):

If $\, a,b\,$ are coprime to $\,m,n\,$ and $\,j,k \equiv 1\,$ mod $\,\phi(n)\,$ and $\,\phi(m)\,$ then, by Euler's theorem,

we deduce $\, a^j+b^k \equiv\, a + b\,$  mod $\,m,n,\,$ so also mod $\,{\rm lcm}(m,n).\,$  OP is special case $\,m,n = 8,125$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Using [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html),  $$\lambda(1000)=\cdots=100$$

As $(309,1000)=1,201\equiv1\pmod{100},$  $$309^{201}\equiv309^1\pmod{1000}$$

Can you take it from here?